# No puedo importar un módulo con Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Tengo esta declaración de un componente nuevo

**category.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CategoryComponent } from './category.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [CategoryComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [ CategoryComponent ]
})
export class CategoryModule { }
```

Este es el selector que viene en

**category.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-category',
  templateUrl: './category.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./category.component.scss']
})
```

Y el HTML tiene solo

```
<p>category works!</p>
```

Necesito usarlo en otro un módulo, ya que repetiré ese componente, lo estoy importando así

**home.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { HomeRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { CategoryModule } from '@components/category/category.module';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HomeRoutingModule,
    CategoryModule,
  ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

Intenté meterlo al

**home.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <app-category></app-category>
  </div>
</div>
```

Me salta este error

> Error: src/app/modules/home/home.component.html:3:5 - error NG8001:
> 'app-category' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'app-category' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'app-category' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>    to suppress this message.
>
> 3     
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> src/app/modules/home/home.component.ts:5:16
> 5   templateUrl: './home.component.html',
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> Error occurs in the template of component HomeComponent.

Mi *shorthand* de rutas está así declarado

```
"paths": {
  "@modules/*": [ "app/modules/*" ],
  "@components/*": [ "app/shared/components/*" ],
  "@services/*": [ "app/shared/services/*" ],
  "@interfaces/*": [ "app/shared/interfaces/*" ],
  "@pipes/*": [ "app/shared/pipes/*" ],
  "@utils/*": [ "app/shared/utils/*" ],
  "@data/*": [ "app/data/*" ],
}
```

No me da errores de importación, solo errores de que no conoce al elemento, ya llevo bastante tiempo con este error, qué hice mal?

> PD. Ya reinicié el VSCode como 1000 veces, levanté el servidor y lo tiré y sigue igual